# Is it possible add member function to data type in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to create a function to data types like in javascript with "String.prototype". Is it possible in C++ too?

For example:

```
int functionName()
{
    if(this.string == "something") {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

std::string mystring = "text";

int result = mystring.functionName();
```

Comment: Not possible in C++. Not like that anyway.

Comment: there are proposals for future c++ versions called _unified function calls_, they come very close to what you want to do. but unfortunately the future is not now.

Comment: Yeah, that's a big 'ol "nope!" Unfortunately for you, not a thing in C++. Maybe this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Perhaps you can explain what you're trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: C++ is not scripting language, many things are done in a different way. Trying to use one language with habits from another usually lead to a disaster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not.

You can inherit from a class and add new members to the new derived class, but also consider *composition* because inheritance isn't always appropriate. Consult the chapter in your book about *object oriented programming* for more information on that.

Also consider free (non-member) functions if you don't need any access to private data. Similarly, be careful of [overdoing it with the getters/setters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12108025/560648)!

Answer (score 2):

You can mimic extension functions in C++, by abusing free-standing operator overloading.  Here I've leveraged `operator->*`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Extension function.
static int functionName(std::string const& self) {
    if (self == "something") {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Thunk glue.
static int operator->*(std::string const& s, int(*fn)(std::string const&)) {
    return fn(s);
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "something";
    int i = s->*functionName;
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

But I strongly urge you to wait until some future C++ standard formally adopts *unified function calls*.

Editorial note: not recommended, as it is not idiomatic C++ and abusing operator overloading is a good way to make you unpopular.  And C++ is already a difficult enough language as is.