# How to legally cast function pointer to method pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm looking for the opposite of `std::mem_fn`: turning a *function pointer* into a *member pointer* (e.g. `void(*)(C*)` to `void(C::*)()` for a given class *C*).

### Background

I'm using a 3rd party library (say *lib1.h*) to create bindings for another 3rd party library (*lib2.h*).

Some functions in *lib1.h* receive method pointers to methods that accept a `Value` argument (also defined in *lib1.h*). In other hand, *lib2.h* classes do not contain such methods, so I have to do the wrappings manually through a lambda function:

```cpp
/* lib1.h (can't touch this) */ 
class Value;
class Property;

template <typename C>
struct ObjectWrap {
  using Method = void(C::*)(Value);
  static Property declare(std::string name, Method method); 
};

/* lib2.h (can't touch this) */ 
struct Person {
  void greet(std::string name);
};

/* bindings.cpp */
std::string value_to_std_string(Value v);

Property declarePersonGreet() {
  return ObjectWrap<Person>::declare("greet",
    /* ERROR */ [](Person* p, Value v) {
      p->greet(value_to_std_string(v));
  });
}
```

I'm fairly confident that I'm not misusing *lib1.h*'s API (and implementing such methods by deriving the classes of *lib2.h* is unfortunately not an option). Therefore I feel that casting to method pointers is the only solution.

Is there any way of legally doing this? I would like to avoid undefined behavior if possible.

Comment: better define `Value` and `Property` and `declare` needs to be public. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/5dPZzp

Comment: Your premise is mistaken - `mem_fn` does not turn a member pointer into a function pointer, it wraps it inside a callable object.

Comment: Almost sounds like you want extension methods in C++.  There's a janky way to mimic extension methods in C++, but I recommend against using the technique in real code.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081233/4641116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do such cast. Even if you could get a `void(Person::*)(Value)`, you could not use that because `Person` has no such method. If lib1 expects a type `C` with a member function `void(C::)(Value)` then there is no way around providing such type `C` with the corresponding method. You can write a wrapper for `Person`:

```
struct Wrapper {    
    Person p;
    void greet(Value v) {
        p.greet(value_to_std_string(v));
    }
};


Property declarePersonGreet() {
  return ObjectWrap<Wrapper>::declare("greet",&Wrapper::greet);
}
```

If you have many classes similar to `Person` you could make the wrapper a template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {    
    T p;
    void greet(Value v) {
        p.greet(value_to_std_string(v));
    }
};
```

...possibly also parameterized on the member function to be called on the wrapped object and the function to be used for converting the parameter.