# Difference in behavior of pointer-to-member access operators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, pointer-to-member

In C++, I'm searching for the crucial sections of the standard
explaining the subtle difference in behavior I've observed between the
language's two pointer-to-member access operators, `.*` and `->*`.

According to my test program shown below, whilst `->*` seems to allow its
right-hand expression to be of any type implicitly convertible to
`pointer to member of S`, `.*` does not so.  When compiling with
gcc and clang, both compilers yield errors for the line marked '(2)'
stating that my class `Offset` cannot be used as a member pointer.

**Test Program**
https://godbolt.org/z/46nMPvKxE

```
#include <iostream>

struct S { int m; };

template<typename C, typename M>
struct Offset
{
    M C::* value;
    operator M C::* () { return value; }  // implicit conversion function
};

int main()
{
    S s{42};
    S* ps = &s;
    Offset<S, int> offset{&S::m};

    std::cout << ps->*offset << '\n';  // (1) ok
    std::cout << s.*offset << '\n';    // (2) error
    std::cout.flush();
}
```

**Compiler Output**

```
GCC 12.2:
    'offset' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'Offset<S, int>'
clang 15.0:
    right hand operand to .* has non-pointer-to-member type 'Offset<S, int>'
```

**Program Variation**

In order to prove that `->*` actually performs an *implicit* conversion using `Offset`'s
conversion function in the test program shown above, I declared it *explicit* for test purposes,

```
    explicit operator M C::* () { return value; }  // no longer implicit conversion function
```

resulting in the compilers to also yield errors for the line marked '(1)':

```
GCC 12.2:
    error: no match for 'operator->*' (operand types are 'S*' and 'Offset<S, int>')
    note: candidate: 'operator->*(S*, int S::*)' (built-in)
    note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'Offset<S, int>' to 'int S::*'
clang 15.0:
    error: right hand operand to ->* has non-pointer-to-member type 'Offset<S, int>'
```

**Research**

Whilst there *is* a well-documented difference between the two operators in that
`->*` is overloadable and `.*` is not, my code obviously does not make use of this option
but rather relies on the built-in `operator ->*` defined for raw pointer type `S*`.

Besides *differences* in overloadability, I merely found documentation stating the *similarity*
of the expressions.  Cited from the standard (https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf):

> [7.6.4.2] The binary operator .* binds its second operand, which shall be of type “pointer to member of T” to its first
> operand, which shall be a glvalue of class T or of a class of which T is an unambiguous and accessible base
> class. The result is an object or a function of the type specified by the second operand.

> [7.6.4.3] [...] The expression E1->*E2 is converted into the equivalent form (*(E1)).*E2.

And cited from cppreference.com (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators):

> The second operand of both operators is an expression of type pointer to member ( data or function) of T or pointer to member of an unambiguous and accessible base class B of T.
> The expression E1->*E2 is exactly equivalent to (*E1).*E2 for built-in types; that is why the following rules address only E1.*E2.

Nowhere have I found a notion of conversion of the right hand operand.

**Question**

What have I overlooked? Can someone point me to an explanation of this difference in behavior?

Comment: What I am curious about is why you would even need a pointer to a member. I've been using C++ for close to 30 years now and never needed it. There is always a better option from a design point of view.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Use cases of pointers-to-member are certainly rare.  I remember applying them when writing wrapper classes for the components of a C library.  In order to avoid boilerplate, I wrote a class template capable of wrapping a couple of structurally similar components.  The policy classes used in conjunction with the template would describe the internals required for the implementation in the form of type aliases, function pointers, and ... pointers to members.

Comment: Interesting puzzle.  You probably should have `language-lawyer` tag on this question.  Does `->*` have the "recursive" behavior that `->` has?

Comment: @Eljay Good point. I added that tag.

Comment: I suspect the answer is that `(*E1).*E2` for built-in types, and `Offset` is not a built-in type.  In conjunction with `->*` participating in overload resolution with user defined operators (like `operator M C::* ()`), but `.*` does not.

Comment: That must have been an interesting piece of code. Good to know it was some "library" internal stuff. :)

Comment: One of my answers was (ab)using `->*` for function extensions.  Not something I recommend, but a fun exercise.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081233/4641116

Comment: @Eljay  I've been tempted to upvote your linked answer and would merely restrain for the very same reason already explained in your editorial note.  As someone killing time with C++ as others might do with a '1000-pieces-black-hell' jigsaw puzzle, I'm reasonably excited.  Feel applauded! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When overloadable operators are used and at least one operand is of class or enumeration type, overload resolution is performed using a candidate set that includes built-in candidates ([[over.match.oper]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3)) - for `->*` in particular, see [[over.built]/9](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#9).

In this case, a built-in candidate is selected, so the implicit conversion is applied to the second operand, and then `->*` is interpreted as the built-in operator ([[over.match.oper]/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#11)).

With `.*`, there's no overload resolution at all, so no implicit conversion either.